# How do I convert the following relation into a recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, exponentiation

I am trying to analyse the time complexity of the fast exponentiation method,
which is given as

$$x^n=
\begin{cases}
 x^\frac{n}{2}.x^\frac{n}{2}       &\text{if n is even}\newline
x.x^{n-1}   &\text{if n is odd} \newline
1 &\text{if n=0}
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to write it as,
$$
T(n)=\begin{cases}
T(\frac{n}{2}).T(\frac{n}{2}) &\text{if n is even}\newline
T(n-1) &\text{if n is odd}\newline
1 &\text{if n=0}
\end{cases}
$$

I think I am lacking somewhere and so not able write correct recurrence relation here.

Need help to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the total number of multiplications.

So the first case for even $n$ would have:

$$T(n) = 1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

because you can share the computation of $x^\frac{n}{2}$, performing one additional multiplication to combine them.